# How does oxygen pump works?

Tags: materials, automotive-engineering

In NOx sensors there are oxygen pumps that pump the oxygen out of the chamber. My question is, the oxygen is obviously pumped through the Zirconia zeolite, but how does it get released from at other side? Does it go through the electrode?